# How can I teach a teenager living with adhd coding

Tags: adhd, programming

I'm an African. I have a teenage relative living with ADHD. I think he's very brilliant. Can someone recommend some online platforms where he can learn how to code or some methods that can help him to code, please

Comment: How’s ADHD related to coding?

Comment: Hi! You might also be interested in https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/search?q=adhd and to a lesser extent https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/search?q=adhd

Comment: Has this teenage relative expressed an interest in programming?  Generally you would want to recommend these things to them if they have expressed an interest - not just because they have a learning disorder. Not every child who has ADHD will have an interest in coding.  Also, Stack Exchange does not usually allow product recommendation questions, as they tend to be inexhaustible lists that can over time lose their quality and also tend to be platforms for product placement.

Comment: @Zibbobz, the relative has expressed interest in programming. I will be teaching him python starting next weekend and write his progress here as a feedback after sometime perhaps it'll help some other parents with kids living with adhd

Comment: @Craving_gold What you are doing for this child is very good!  I commend you for taking an interest in their passion, and especially in trying to help them achieve their own goals in life.  I do however have to inform you that "posting feedback" and "progress updates" on StackExchange is not really how the site works - this is a Question and Answer site, and it is really only meant for posting questions and providing concrete answers.  If you really want to teach your relative Python though, I can recommend w3 as a good learning resource - https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp

Comment: If you live in Bénin then there is "Ilo Robot", a robot that can be programmed in python as well as without python using block programming. I think it's been deployed to a few schools to teach programming to children

Comment: @Zibbobz, noted

Answer (score 2):

Programming is something very useful and it can be very fun. The most important thing is that he programs something that he likes, not something that could be "useful for his future".

The programming language you choose is not important per se, so instead of choosing a programming language choose a topic.

Maybe he likes electronics, mounting stuff that moves, makes sound and has lights.

In this case you could start with an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) based robot, or kit (there are many out there with different prices and complexities). This will not only teach programming but also electronics, maybe a bit of mechanics, and at the end it's something physical you can still play with once you close the laptop.

Maybe he likes programming a small game, something visual you can control with the keys and mouse and that is not only fun to program but something you can then play and show your friends. I'd personally recommend  [The coding train](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HerCR8bw_GE&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA)  I linked a playlist of a tutorial using a library of Javascript to create animations and games but also teaches the basics about geometry, vectors and other useful stuff to work with animations.

There are many other topics and tutorials that he could follow, just make sure he likes what he is learning and that he keeps challenged and doesn't get bored.

Comment: You are right, Elerium. We had an intro into python via colab last weekend . I could tell it seemed boring to him. He also complained it's kinda too academic (Though I don't think so). I have been thinking of how to spice things up before next weekend and this came right on time. Spot on.